# Best way in iOS and Swift to store a server-supplied credential between app launches

Tags: ios, swift3, persistent-storage, persistent-data

I need to store a persistent remember token (a string) between app launches and device restarts. The token will be provided by a server once my user logs into the app and its back end service (which is already built). Specifically, I need to set up a persistent data placeholder for the remember token but I don't ever want the code to actually set the value of that placeholder.

On the one hand, it seemed like NSUserDefaults (now called [UserDefaults](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/userdefaults)) was a simple way to do this, but after reading the documentation, it doesn't seem like that was the intention of the feature. All the documentation I've see shows setting it up by assigning a value to a key. I definitely don't want to ever have the app assign a value to that key.

What's the simplest way to do this?

Comment: Not clear what you really want... I understand that you want to store a string (your *token*) then UserDefaults is the solution, why do you say no? Just store your token as value for a key of your choice ("token", or "credential"). So you will be able to retrieve the token given the keu.

Comment: It was not clear how to just set up the data structure without applying a value.

Comment: Something in your app has to do something to make your token persistent.  If assigning a value isn't an option, how do you imagine saving the information you receive?

Comment: One option is to use keychain to store elements like token and credentials securely to the device. Unlike UserDefaults, the info will not get erased after uninstalling the app. A factory reset will reset the keychain. So Keychain should be appropriate to store your token. Apple provides a wrapper class for accessing keychain functionality: https://gist.github.com/vtourraine/1409718

Comment: I can't tell what you want. You're getting a token from your server and you want to save it. But you also say you don't want your code to ever save the value. Do you want to save it or not? If you do, what do you mean that you don't ever want your code to save the value?

Comment: Keychain might be the answer. To be clear, the imperfect analog for what I'm looking for is, if you're building a database-backed server application, you would set up the (usually empty) data structure outside running code base of the application via migrations. Then the application merely creates records and stores data in that structure. I'm looking for a way (and a design pattern really) to somehow set up a trivially simple structure (a simple string) once without applying any value to that string. That string should remain empty until the server provides the token.

Comment: Probably not going to use the Keychain solution as I don't want to get into Objective C.

Comment: The keychain is what you want. It is accessible from Swift. But as Tom  said, your code is going to be responsible for saving the value in the keychain. How else is a value going to get there?  Your server can't update your device directly.

Comment: @TomHarrington What I mean is the all the tutorials and and documentation that I have found for UserDefaults show that to setting it up involves setting up a key/value pair and assigning some value to that key. I want to just set up the key, but leave it empty until the server provides a a value at login.

Comment: What do you mean by "set up" the key?

Comment: @TomHarrington: I mean declaring the key. Every place I've seen it referenced, it shows declaring the key while simultaneously assigning a value like so: `let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults() defaults.setObject("Coding Explorer", forKey: "userNameKey")` I want to be able to declare the key but not (ever) hard code any kind of a value.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to achieve that while also taking security into consideration is to use the Keychain. Data stored in the Keychain is encrypted using the key one provides for example when setting the Touch ID support.

You should never, ever, ever, use UserDefaults for such a task. The reason is UserDefaults are backed by the simple, unencrypted .plist file that is a part of your bundle, and can be more or less easily viewed by anyone that can get access to your ipa (e.g. anyone with jailbroken device).

The KeychainAccess API is written in Objective-C, but there are numerous wrappers that encapsulate this using Swift. You can use this on https://github.com/kishikawakatsumi/KeychainAccess